# WSO2 Api Manager - Deploy in EC2 and change default ports

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm deploying the latest **WSO2 API Manager** (1.2.0) on an EC2 VM.
I would like to change the default ports as listed below:

- change carbon port from `9443` to `8090`
- change store and publisher ports from `9763` to `8080`
- change the api port from `8280` to `80`

I have been looking around for a while and have not found any guide/tutorial describing how to do that.

Many thanks in advance for any URL/info/help on this.

Answer (score 4):

In WSO2 API Manager (1.2.0)  there are two transports.
 1.HttpCore + NIO extensions:Used by api gateway(api).
 2.Tomcat servlet transport :used by carbon management console and web apps(store and publishers)

You can change port number of those transports.

According to your requirement,

To change the port of api edit following in API_MANAGER_HOME/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml

a)

```
<transportReceiver name="http" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.HttpCoreNIOListener">
<parameter name="port" locked="false">80</parameter>
```

b)

```
<transportReceiver name="https" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.HttpCoreNIOSSLListener">
        <parameter name="port" locked="false">443</parameter>
```

To change the port of carbon ,store and publisher edit followings in  API_MANAGER_HOME/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml

a)

```
<Connector  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                port="8080"
```

b)

```
<Connector  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                port="8090"
```